# How many math columns are allowed in math cases (ConTeXt)?

Tags: math-mode, align, context

In ConTeXt, when using the cases environment, it seems to allow one `\MC` (giving 2 columns) only, and when I place a second `\MC` (giving 3 columns), the columns are not aligned, and the math variables are not properly displayed as italic.
Is there only 2 columns allowed here?

```
\starttext

\placeformula \startformula \startalign
\NC A (m_1,m_2) =
\NC \startcases
{\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \quad m_1 =\MC 2m_1'-1,\; m_2 =\MC 2m_2'-1  \NR
{\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')), \quad m_1 =\MC 2m_1',\; m_2 =\MC 2m_2'-1  \NR
-{\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')), \quad m_1 =\MC 2m_1'-1,\; m_2 =\MC 2m_2'  \NR
{\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \quad m_1 =\MC 2m_1',\; m_2 =\MC 2m_2'  \NR
\stopcases \NR[+]
\stopalign \stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are referring to the `cases` environment, aren't you?

Comment: Yes. Let me edit the post.

Comment: `{\rm Re}`… brrr.  The correct way would be `\setupmathlabeltext[Re=Re]\definemathcommand[Re][nolop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{Re}}` and then use `\Re`.

Comment: Sorry, new to ConTeXt, and I don't know what is the `\mathfrak` equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mathcases` environment in ConTeXt is modeled after the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package in LaTeX. Like `amsmath` it only allows two "columns", one for the *value* and one for the *condition*. The general syntax is

```
\startcases
   \NC value \NC condition \NR
   \NC value \NC condition \NR
\stopcases
```

where the second column is typeset as normal text or

```
\startcases
   \NC value \MC condition \NR
   \NC value \MC condition \NR
\stopcases
```

where the second column is typeset as math.

So, for your example:

```
\starttext

\placeformula \startformula 
  A (m_1,m_2) =
  \startcases
    \NC {\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC m_1 = 2m_1'-1,\; m_2 = 2m_2'-1  \NR
    \NC {\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC m_1 = 2m_1',\; m_2 = 2m_2'-1    \NR
    \NC -{\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')),\MC m_1 = 2m_1'-1,\; m_2 = 2m_2'    \NR
    \NC {\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC m_1 = 2m_1',\; m_2 = 2m_2'      \NR
  \stopcases
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

To improve readability, you can try:

```
\placeformula \startformula 
  A (m_1,m_2) =
  \startcases
    \NC {\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC (m_1, m_2) = (2m_1'-1, 2m_2'-1)  \NR
    \NC {\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC (m_1, m_2) = (2m_1', 2m_2'-1)    \NR
    \NC -{\rm Im} (A (m_1',m_2')),\MC (m_1, m_2) = (2m_1'-1, 2m_2')    \NR
    \NC {\rm Re} (A (m_1',m_2')), \MC (m_1, m_2) = (2m_1', 2m_2')      \NR
  \stopcases
\stopformula
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was lazy about that because that was not the core of what the OP asked